# How to split a string into multiple columns by a given pattern?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have text data as given below:

```
\r\n    \r\n        How to get a confirm ticket?\r\n        \r\n            I want to get a tatkal ticket confirm ...
```

How to extract two columns from this data?

I have tried `str_split_fixed()` which divide into four columns and after those four column, two column can be retrieved ... But I want that straight forward it gives only two columns.

```r
x <- "\r\n    \r\n        How to get a confirm ticket?\r\n        \r\n            I want to get a tatkal ticket confirm ..."
str_split_fixed(x, "\r\n", 4)
#>      [,1] [,2]   [,3]                                   [,4]                                                               
#> [1,] ""   "    " "        How to get a confirm ticket?" "        \r\n            I want to get a tatkal ticket confirm ..."
str_split_fixed(x, "\r\n", 4)[1, 3]
#> [1] "        How to get a confirm ticket?"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the strings are always in that same format, the following regular expression should work well:

```r
library(stringr)
x <- "\r\n    \r\n        How to get a confirm ticket?\r\n        \r\n            I want to get a tatkal ticket confirm ..."
str_split(x, "(\r\n\\s*)+", simplify = TRUE)[, -1, drop = FALSE]
     [,1]                           [,2]                                       
[1,] "How to get a confirm ticket?" "I want to get a tatkal ticket confirm ..."
```

If your data actually comes from a table in a text file or from a web page, there are probably more convenient options.

Comment: Thank you. I have another string  :  500words\n    \n    \n        \n    \n    \n       Author\n        \n

Comment: how to do for this

Comment: I would recommend learning regular expressions (e.g., [link](https://stat545.com/block022_regular-expression.html)). Here, the pattern separating the strings seems to be something like `"(\n\\s*)+"`?!?